# Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later. (code 2, subcode null)

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, restfb

We are using restfb 1.6.14. I am getting the following error while fetching the public posts.

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of
 type OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your reques
t later. (code 2, subcode null)
        at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.
exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:964)
        at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusException
IfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:885)
        at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(Defaul
tFacebookClient.java:824)
        at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.ja
va:765)
        at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.ja
va:729)
        at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchConnection(DefaultFacebookClien
t.java:271)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Getting the access token using the following code,

```
AccessToken accessToken = new
    DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(appid,appsecret);
    String token=accessToken.getAccessToken();
```

Getting public posts using the following source code,

```
public Connection<Post> publicSearchMessages(String keyword, int limit) {
    Connection<Post> messages = fbClient.fetchConnection("search",
            Post.class, Parameter.with("q", keyword),
            Parameter.with("limit", limit), Parameter.with("type", "post"));

    return messages;
}
```

Why this error occurred? How do I solve this error??

Answer (score 0):

With Graph API 2.0 you are not allowed to search for posts, even public one.